# Cannot install baxter simulator in ROS Indigo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install Baxter simulator so that I may use it with Moveit without connecting to a real Baxter robot. I have followed the following tutorial:

link:[Baxter Wiki](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation)

When I try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gazebo2 ros-indigo-qt-build ros-indigo-driver-common ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-indigo-ros-control ros-indigo-control-toolbox ros-indigo-realtime-tools ros-indigo-ros-controllers ros-indigo-xacro python-wstool ros-indigo-tf-conversions ros-indigo-kdl-parser
```

I get the following error:

```
 Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I also tried this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-baxter-simulator
```

The same issue exists. Why the packages are not found?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325837/cannot-install-baxter-simulator-in-ros-indigo/) by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2019-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does a `sudo apt update` complete successfully?

Could it be that you're running into #q325039?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on 2019-06-14**:
It did not fix the issue.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-14**:
Then you'll need to show us the output of `sudo apt update` and of the `sudo apt-get install ..` command.

Please copy-paste errors and messages *verbatim*. Do **not** paraphrase errors.

**Comment by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on 2019-06-14**:
Oh it did actually, after doing the sudo update

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-14**:
So this was #q325039?

**Comment by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on 2019-06-14**:
Yes, it was